# SSRS report Subscription History

Tags: reporting-services

I wanted the count of number of subscriptions of a report , Did a lot of research but unable to get the detail.
I did used Catalog and Execution log table , which just gives number of times report got executed but not the history of count of subscription with different parameters , Request any to provide any hint to acheive the task

Answer (score 0):

[ExecutionLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view?view=sql-server-ver15#bkmk_executionlog) will return one record for every time a report was executed that is available based on your history retention.

What your looking for is the Subscription table.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.Catalog            AS CAT
    JOIN dbo.Subscriptions AS SUB
        ON CAT.ItemID = SUB.Report_OID
WHERE
    CAT.[Name] = 'My Report Name';
```